# Warning using the Package Robot_localization

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

Just a question, Is it normal the next WARNING using the package Robot_localization? :

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:

- /ekf_localization:

  - /set_pose

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225375/warning-using-the-package-robot_localization/) by [Fenix](https://answers.ros.org/users/22603/fenix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

'ekf_localization' is subscribed to '/set_pose', but nothing is publishing it. I think that's a ROS-level warning, and doesn't originate within 'ekf_localization_node' itself.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fenix](https://answers.ros.org/users/22603/fenix/) on 2016-02-10**:
Thank you so much Tom.